# Should I manually position Node or make it a child of a parent

Tags: sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have a person SKSpriteNode sprite. He is picking up an apple with his hands which is roughly half of his height(middle-right edge of sprite). Should I make this apple a child of the sprite or should I just calculate the position manually on each update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the apple sprite must move according to the hand sprite then make the apple child of the hand and let SpriteKit do the work for you.

> Also other geometrical transformations (like rotation and scaling) are automatically reflected from the parent to the child as well.

As a rule of thumb try to write the less possible code into the update method.